# Real time data on a webserver AT COMMANDS

Tags: websocket, webserver, esp8266, esp32, at-command

I succeded to make a webserver (access point ) which is showing an HTML code, using an esp32 and an stm32 which is sending the at commands to it. How I can do if I want to show on a webpage in real-time data from a sensor? I heard that I need to use WebSocket but I didn't find so much.

Comment: If you have an ESP32, why not skip the STM32 and just run the web server on the ESP32?

Comment: That's the requirement

Comment: Whether need Websocket depend on application. If you only want to display some sensor data on webpage, it is not a must. You will need web socket if you have event-based data coming from the sensor.

Comment: Yes, I need to display some sensor data, but I don't want to refresh the page so that I can see the value in "real-time".